# Multiple image upload in single Request using AFNetworking

Tags: ios5, afnetworking, multipartform-data

I want to upload multiple image in single request, I manage to make it work when sending single image data. here is my code for sending single image data :

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseUrl: my_url ];

NSMutableRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:nil
parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData: my_imageData name:@"image" fileName: @"myImage.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: request];

[operation start];
```

on the server side, I use Spring MVC. this is the Web service/ end point that will receive the request that contains multiple image:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test-multiple-upload/{collateralid}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String multipartfilesUpload(
        @PathVariable("collateralid") Long collId,
        @RequestParam("images[]") CommonsMultipartFile[] images) {

    //proccess the image data. save to local or to DB


    return "uploaded successful";
}
```

My question is how to make the multipartForm request using AFNetworking with multiple image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that by using the same name of appended data will make the data as Array in server side. therefore:

```
NSArray *imageArray;
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseUrl: my_url ];

NSMutableRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:nil
parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
      for(UIImage *img in imageArray)
      {
            [formData appendPartWithFileData: my_imageData name:@"image" fileName:@"myImage.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
      }
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: request];

[operation start];
```

considering every imageData will be appended in form data multipart request with the same name tags as "**image**".
On server side it'll be handled as array, "**CommonsMultipartFile[] image**" .